# Is this a Safari CSS transition bug?

Tags: css, safari

I've run into a wierd error that I suspect is a Safari CSS bug. What happens is that the element being animated *disappears* during the CSS transition, and re-appears at its end. This error happens only on Safari. It works OK on Chrome and Firefox. Furthermore, it also works OK if the initial position of the element being animated is less than half the page's width.

If you're using Safari, you can see the problem here: http://yodesign.se/transition-anomaly/

Resize your browser window so that the text is close to the right edge of the window. Click the Move button. The text disappears briefly and then re-appears in its new location. press Unmove to move it back.

Now make the browser window very wide, so the text (in its Unmoved position) is at the center of the window, and try again. The animation now works as expected.

Here's the complete code:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="move(true)">Move</button>
<button onclick="move(false)">Unmove</button>
    <div id="mover" style="position: relative;transition: transform 0.5s;">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 800px;">
            <div>Close to right edge</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function move(doMove) {
        document.getElementById('mover').style.transform = doMove ? "translate(-300px, 0)" : "translate(0, 0)";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

It's possible there's something I'm overlooking in the CSS that causes this error to occur, but since it works OK in other browsers (and when making the window wider in Safari), I suspect it's a Safari CSS bug. The initial code comes out of a CMS system, and the snippet shown above is a greatly simplified version that still shows the error. So I'm not helped by suggestions on how to re-arrange the "web page" to make it work. I've reproduced this on Safari 13.01 as well as webkit nightly build.

-JM

Comment: Thanks. Fixed (both in the snippet above and the runnable code). But it makes no difference for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s to the style

Comment: Made no difference to my problem. I don't think Safari has needed those prefixes for transition for quite some time. -JM